# ng-bootstrap timepicker format 09:30 AM and 12 hours format issue?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, timepicker

Using ng-bootstrap first time, after implementing ng-bootstrap timepicker, it's return the value in format:

Selected time: {
  "hour": 13,
  "minute": 30
}

Don't see much option in documentation. I am looking to achieve HH:MM AM/PM, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [custom NgbTimeAdapter](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples#adapter). Or format the current value. Smg like:

```
function formatNgbTime(time: NgbTimeModel):string {
   const isPm = time.hours > 12;
   return `${isPm ? time.hours - 12 : time.hours}:${time.minutes} {isPm ? 'PM' : 'AM'}`
}
```

You might also consider using some date library for formating. [The good overview of modern js datetime libraries.](https://blog.logrocket.com/javascript-date-libraries/)